# Rayman Legends & Origins from PS Vita to PS4

Tags: ps4, ps-vita, rayman-legends

I owned a PS Vita and have Rayman Origins and Rayman legends on it, I'm on the advance levels. I just bought PS4 and wanted to know how I can play Rayman on my PS4, and really wanted to continue from where I left on PS Vita.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I don't think this is possible. Sorry but as of now I don't think you can do that.

Comment: 2nd to this. It isn't possible to do that kind of play unfortunately. You can do remote play from the PS4 to the PS VIta, but not the reverse.

Also, some games DO share online saves which can be shared between consoles using PSN but Rayman Legends isn't one of these.